# Vuetify v-treeview how to get the last selected element?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify v-treeview how to get the get last selected element?

```
<v-treeview
   v-model="treeModel"
   :items="items"
   selectable="selectable"            
>
```

by treeModel I have all selected, but **how can I get only the last item selected (clicked)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by only providing the last item's id in the `v-model`

modified example from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview#checkbox-color

### option 1 - use v-on/@on update:active

** DOES NOT CURRENTLY WORK FOR VUETIFY v2 **

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-treeview
      v-model="selection"
      selectable
      selected-color="red"
      :items="items"
      @update:active="onUpdate"
    ></v-treeview>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    selection: [],
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Applications :',
        children: [
          { id: 2, name: 'Calendar : app' },
          { id: 3, name: 'Chrome : app' },
          { id: 4, name: 'Webstorm : app' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Documents :',
        children: [
          { id: 6, name: 'Calendar.doc' },
          { id: 7, name: 'Chrome.doc' },
          { id: 8, name: 'Webstorm.doc' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    onUpdate(selection) {
      console.log(selection)
    }
  }
})
```

the problem is that if you're using vuetify v2.0.0 - v2.0.5 the action does not actually work for a selection but for activatable

````
## option 2 - use watch

this option, at the moment, is preferred. It uses a watch to trigger the action when the `v-model` changes

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-treeview
      v-model="selection"
      :items="items"
      selectable
    ></v-treeview>
  </v-app>
</div>
````

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  watch:{
    selection(newValue) {
      this.onUpdate(newValue)
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    selection: [],
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Applications :',
        children: [
          { id: 2, name: 'Calendar : app' },
          { id: 3, name: 'Chrome : app' },
          { id: 4, name: 'Webstorm : app' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Documents :',
        children: [
          { id: 6, name: 'Calendar.doc' },
          { id: 7, name: 'Chrome.doc' },
          { id: 8, name: 'Webstorm.doc' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    onUpdate(selection) {
      console.log(selection)
    }
  }
})
```

If you want to find the last item that was selected, you can use an array diff here

```js
  watch:{
    selection(newValue, oldVal) {
      var arrDiff = myArrDiffDependency.added(newValue, oldValue)
      this.onUpdate(arrDiff)
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel for your answer, I need to get the slected item fter every active item change. It can be done with v-on:update:active="update" and methods: {update:function(data){this.activeItem=data;}}. If you update your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: updated the answer. I'm not sure what version of vuetify you're using, but if it's v2.0 you may need to use a watch instead of the action, or use activatable instead of selection (unless that's what you wanted in the first place)

Answer (score -1):

```
  watch: {
    selection() {
      if (this.items.length > 1) {
        this.items.shift();
      }
    },
  },
```

Isto resolve

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).